# Mac Catalina (10.15.4) Postfix -- can't send email from command line and mail.log doesn't exist

Tags: php, macos, email, postfix-mta

Mac Catalina (10.15.4) Postfix -- can't send email from command line and mail.log doesn't exist

I'm running MacOS Catalina (10.15.4) and trying to send email from the command line (so I can later send email from a webpage using PHP), but my /var/log/mail.log is missing.  I tried creating mail.log by hand using:

```
> sudo touch /var/log/mail.log
```

but postfix error messages are still not being written to mail.log.  I tried to change the mail.log owner to _postifx:

```
> sudo chown root:admin mail.log
```

but received the following error message:

```
> sudo chown _postifx:wheel mail.log 
> chown: _postifx: illegal user name
```

Email is not being sent, or, at least, not arriving at in my email box when sent from the command line using:

```
date | mail -s "Test Email" [email username]@gmail.com
```

When I run `mailq`, the output is:

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
93059425861       347 Fri May 22 04:20:10  [machine username]@[machine name].local
(connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c08::6c]:587: No route to host)
[email username]@gmail.com`
```

I'm normally on a VPN, but I have tested sending email from the command line both on and off the VPN and I get the same error message in `mailq`.

My sasl_passwd has one entry:

[smtp.gmail.com]:587 [email username]@gmail.com:[password]

where I know [email username] and [password] (there are no [] surrounding the "email username" and "password" in sasl_passwd) are correct.

The only critical (I think) uncommented lines in /etc/postfix/main.cf are:

```
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = _postfix
myhostname = smtp.gmail.com
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = _postdrop
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
recipient_delimiter = +
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_use_tls = yes`
```

1. How do I get error messages written to `/var/log/mail.log`?
   and
2. How do I get email to successfully send from the command line (so I can ultimately send email via PHP in a webpage)?

Comment: Did you get a fix of sorts?

Comment: No, not yet. Can you help?

Comment: I wish. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Faced the same issue (in my case it turned out to be missing [] around smtp host in sasl_passwd). The following command `log stream --predicate '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp") || (process == "master")' --info` helps with debugging (run it in separate terminal window, realtime log). Also another thing I came across was in Gmail setting to allow less secure apps to be on (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)... hope it pushes you the right direction

Comment: for future reference, the previous comment got me past the error. This is what it looks like `smtp.gmail.com:587 notme@gmail.com:[notmypassword123]` after running `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, David Jermans command helped

```
log stream --predicate '(process == "smtpd") || (process == "smtp") || (process == "master")' --info
```

there were indications telling me to include

```
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

_

```
sasl_passwd had to be completely without square brackets
```

additionally I needed to edit the /etc/postfix/generic file and add

```
@mac16.localhost    serverloginmail@domain.com
```

followed of a

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

and

```
sudo postfix reload
```

my main.cf file looks like this

```
mail_owner=_postfix
setgid_group=_postdrop
myhostname=mac16.localhost
compatibility_level=2
relayhost=mail.domain.com:465
#Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain
#Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode=yes
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```